# Are the following two logical expressions equivalent?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I was asked to express the  following  using existential  and  universal  quantifiers: "There  is  at  least  one  and  at  most  two  students  in  this  class  who  have  sent  email to every student in the class."

We were given the prepositional function $S(x,y)$ which is true if $x$ sent an email to $y$, and false otherwise. Where $x$ and $y$ are part of the domain of all students in the class.

The answer I produced was: $∃x∃y∀c( S(x,c) ∧ S(y,c) ) ∧ ∃x∃y∃z∀m( (S(x,m) ∧ S(y,m) ∧ S(z,m) → ((z=x) ∨ (z=y)) )$.

Through the above statement I tried to communicate the idea that: That there are students x and y s.t. they sent an email to every student in the class, and there is a student c s.t. c sent an email to every student in the class and is equal to either x or y.

I was told this was wrong and that the right answer is:
$∃x[∀yS(x,y) ∧ ∀u∀v(u=x ∨ v=x ∨ u=v ∨ ∃y(¬S(u,y) ∨ ¬S(v,y)))] $

This is the equivalent of saying: "I can find one student who has sent an email to every student, but there cannot be a pair of students, both of which are different from the original student I picked and from each other, and both of which have sent an email to every student."

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Does "every student" require that the student sent an e-mail to him/herself ?

Comment: If the right answer is right, then yes.

Comment: @Peter a student could send an email to him/herself

Comment: @Peter "every" means "every" (it certainly does so in the given colution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are always many ways to express the desired concept, the given solution is just one of them, see below. So in principle, it could be the case that *both* your attempt *and* the given solution are correct.
However, this i snot the case

Your attempt is of the form $\Phi\land\Psi$, where  the first part
$$\Phi:\equiv∃x∃y∀c( S(x,c) ∧ S(y,c) ) $$
can be simplified to
$$∃x∀c( S(x,c) ) $$
(and so stands for "There is at least one student who ...") because nothing prevents $x=y$.
The main problem is with your second part
$$ \Psi:\equiv∃x∃y∃z∀m( (S(x,m) ∧ S(y,m) ∧ S(z,m) → ((c=x) ∨ (c=y)) ) $$
because it has a free $c$ in it. I suppose you wanted $m$ there (and an extra closing parenthesis), i.e.,
$$ ∃x∃y∃z∀m( (S(x,m) ∧ S(y,m) ∧ S(z,m)) → ((m=x) ∨ (m=y)) ) $$
However, this expresses nothing really helpful. Indeed, this $\Psi$ is satisfied for example if there exists a student who sent no mail at all.
Thus your attempt would also be satisfied by four students $A,B,C,D$ where $A,B,C$ write to all students and $D$ writes to no one. This is not supposed to be the case.

---

**Fixing your idea:**
I like your first part however because it allows $x,y$ to be either different and be the two writing-to-all students or $x=y$ is the one writing-to-all student. What is missing, however, is to express (within the scope of the same $\exists x\exists y$!) that not other apart from these two (or this one) is a writing-to-all student; that is: if $z$ is a writing-to-all student then $z=x$ or $z=y$:
$$\forall z((\forall m S(z,m))\to (z=x\lor z=y)) $$
so in full (recycling the $c$ for $z$):
$$∃x∃y∀c( S(x,c) ∧ S(y,c) \land ((\forall m S(c,m)) \to (c=x\lor c=y)))$$

I find my solution easier to read because it is shorter and less convoluted.

In addition, if you prefer all quantifiers at the beginning, you can transform mine to

$$∃x∃y∀c\exists m( S(x,c) ∧ S(y,c) \land (S(c,m) \to (c=x\lor c=y)))$$

Comment: I'm not sure, and it's been a while, but I vaguely remember the scope of quantifiers to be rather large. So, I wondered if the c was actually free. Maybe it's not intended, but the way I read it, it was bound when it still was there).

Comment: I think the $\exists m$ in the last line should read $\forall m$.